# Can Windows XP run with just 512 MB of RAM?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, laptop

I have heard of older-ish Lenovo Ideapad notebooks that come with barely 512 MB of DDR2 RAM and they run full Windows XP, which is supposedly in need of over 400 MB of RAM to work efficiently. Given that OS uses that much, how little would be available for other apps?

This is what I heard:

Windows 95/98 can run on at least 8 MB of RAM.

Windows 2000/ME need over 100 MB.

Windows XP needs over 400 MB for efficiently; possibly can run under it though.

Windows Vista/7 need over 600 MB.

Windows 8 needs pretty much 1 GB itself, no questions asked.

Non-Windows:

OS X Snow Leopard/Mavericks/Mountain Lion demand over 800 MB of RAM.

Ubuntu Linux 12 and up need at least 350 MB of RAM.

Android Gingerbread generally needs over 80 MB of RAM, considering various builds of it.

iOS 7 only needs 100 MB of RAM, so it usually leaves 400 + MB to the rest of programs.

Blackberry 10.1 uses 200 MB of RAM.

Comment: Can't be a duplicate because I'm not asking how it can run on 256 MB.

Comment: I admit it's not an exact duplicate, but it shows that it can run on 256MB of RAM, and gives lots of info on how to ensure things run well on memory-restricted systems.  That plus the fact that the minimum memory requirements for XP are [published by MS and easily accessible](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/314865) (hint: Minimum 64MB, but that's just to run Windows XP itself).

Comment: SP level makes a difference too, but: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/314865

Comment: Windows XP-SP2 512M, Windows XP-SP3 1G. After much observation on how well systems would run. Don't have to worry anymore, Windows XP has been exorcised from the building.

Answer (score 1):

yes, XP can work just fine with 512MB of RAM.

In the early XP era computers used to have less than that and I remember upgrading all or office desktops to a whopping 256MB. After that they ran fine, even with huge memory consuming programs such as McAffee and Outlook open at the same time.  (Memory usage with those open was just shy of 200MB. The exact OS was XP prof. SP2).

Twice 256MB should be just fine. Even 128MB should be fine for just the OS.

Just do not try to open firefox in it with a 100 open tabs and a few flash appl running. (Or IE, or opera, or ...). But for the OS alone 128MB should be enough leaving you with 384MiB for applications.

Comment: It won't be fine if a program needs hundreds of MB of RAM though (specifically 200 MB and over); that may push it to its RAM limits before segfaults. It's impossible to have more than 300 MB of free RAM with XP installed on a 512 MB max though.

Comment: Free RAM might as well be in a drawer. RAM should be used. Either for programs or as cache. Even XP did that.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying. I am saying that 300 MB of free RAM is not that much for programs that could use it. It's enough for programs like maybe MilkShape, PSX, PSP and n64 emulators, but it's tipping the scales with MilkShape 3D even. No way could Photoshop run reliably under heavy load with just 300 MB of RAM.

Comment: Ok. However there is not much you can change about that. And the same is true for any OS. You can try to tweak Xp to use less memory, but even if the OS used no memory at all you are going to be limited by 512MB total. I do not expect there to be much difference between 512MB - $stock_OS_usage or 512MB - $tweaked_XP_usage. Either way 512MB is little for a modern app. So do not run those or increase the memory.

Comment: As for the title: "Can Windows XP run with just 512 MB of RAM?". Since it can run with 1/8th of that the answer remains yes. But if your question is not about that then please adjust the title to match.